# How to make searchable pdf with tesseract from C++

Tags: c++, qt, tesseract

I'm going to receive images from Qt (QImage) which I then Turn into PDF. But now I need to make them searchable. How can I do this using Tesseract API from code ?

Basically, I want to do following but from code (I'm using C++ but will happily accept answer for other lang)

```sh
$ tesseract -l eng+mar mydoc.jpg out pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract-OCR is written in C++ and tesseract (executable) is example how to use Tesseract API. So just read the source.

Answer (score -1):

Example creating searchable pdf from image in C++:

```
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <tesseract/renderer.h>

int main()
{
    const char* input_image = "/usr/src/tesseract-oc/testing/phototest.tif";
    const char* output_base = "my_first_tesseract_pdf";
    const char* datapath = "/Projects/OCR/tesseract/tessdata";
    int timeout_ms = 5000;
    const char* retry_config = nullptr;
    bool textonly = false;
    int jpg_quality = 92;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    if (api->Init(datapath, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    tesseract::TessPDFRenderer *renderer = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(
              output_base, api->GetDatapath(), textonly, jpg_quality);

    bool succeed = api->ProcessPages(input_image, retry_config, timeout_ms, renderer);
    if (!succeed) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error during processing.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    api->End();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/APIExample.html